# connect to paltalk server using a proxy

Tags: vmware, proxy, connection, port

I want to use paltalk, which is a kind of chat software, but the ports that this applications uses are closed in my country. What I need to do is to use a proxy server. Unfortunately the software itself does not provide a proxy setting. I though it would be possible to run paltalk on an O.S. installed on a virtual machine (say virtualbox) and configure the network setting of virtual machine to direct all its traffic through a proxy on host Operating system, but I could not find a way to do so neither.
can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, however that won't help you from your description.

What you want to do is sign up with a commercial "hotspot vpn" style service to get around those sort of restrictions. That sort of service is usually much cheaper then buying a VM somewhere just to use as a proxy.

Comment: VPN is also not available in my country as well :(